# Server Sent Events with SQL

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, server-sent-events

I can't seem to find a way to do this, so I decided to ask here. I am making an asp.net site which uses data from a SQL Server database. I am using javascript to get the data and format it as I want.

The issue is that I want to use server sent events in order to get the new entry in my database and display it in the page of the site. So far the only examples I saw were with timers on the server side and on the period they send data to the javascript. But I can't seem to figure out how I should do it so that when a new row enters the database to fire the event. 
That should be done on server side but I don't have a clue where to begin.

Comment: signalR is like socket.io for .net land

Comment: I need to use server sent events unfortunately, I saw the idea with signalR but it won't do here

Comment: if you mean to talk to JS's EventSource, that's just a slightly-modified http response. you can use an sql trigger/stored proc to fire off the sse response (if you broadcast), or send it from the same place you talk to the DB and client.

Answer (score 0):

SqlDependency:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring

*Using the  SqlDependency Class is a good way to make your data driven application (whether it be Web or Windows Forms) more efficient by removing the need to constantly re-query your database checking for data changes.*

*That’s how you use the SqlDependency Class for monitoring data changes in your database without having to use something like a timer control to re-query at certain intervals.*

Here is an old book mark:

http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/